# opengl - how do I change texels in a texture only within a certain rectangle area?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I know that a computationally efficient way to do if-else statements is the `mix` and `step` combo, like the following for example:

```
procTexel = mix(tA, tB, step(1.250, time))
```

How do I do it with rectangles, as in, how can I check if a texel is within my desired rectangle area within the texture coordinate (let's say, `vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.55, 0.55)`)? Is it a simple if-elseif-else check, or is there an even better way?

EDIT: the `vec4` I referred to as the 'rectangle area' follows `vec4(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)`.

Comment: maybe the second answer could help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle `AB = vec2(xmax, ymin) - vec2(xmin, ymin); AD = vec2(ymax, xmin) - vec2(xmin, ymin);  AM = vec2(x,y) - vec2(xmin, ymin)`

Comment: I'm talking about the most computationally efficient way, not the basic principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GLSL function [`step(edge, x)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml) returns 0.0 if `x < edge`, and 1.0 else.

This means, that the result of

```
step(edge, x)
```

is equal to

```
x >= edge ? 1.0 : 0.0
```

The following line of code sets the variable `float in_range` to 1.0, if **`x >= a`** and **`x <= b`**, and sets the variable to 0.0 else:

```
float in_range = step(a, x) * step(x, b);
```

Note, this only works if `a <= b`.

If you want to test, if the `vec2 v` is in the rectangle defined by the 2 vectors `vec2 v_min` and `vec2 v_max`, the it can be done like this:

```
vec2  range_test = step(v_min, v) * step(v, v_max); 
float in_rect    = range_test.x * range_test.y;
```

Of course, this only works if `v_min.x <= v_max.x` and `v_min.y <= v_max.y`.

This means, you can write your code somehow like this:

```
vec2  tex_coord = ....;
vec4  rect      = vec4(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);

vec2  in_rect   = step(rect.xy, tex_coord) * step(tex_coord, rect.zw); 
procTexel       = mix(tA, tB, in_rect.x * in_rect.y);
```